# Pushforward of hyperplane class of hyperplane section in Chow ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-space, intersection-theory

Say I have a closed embedding $i : S \hookrightarrow Y$ where $Y$ is a degree $d$ smooth projective threefold, and $S$ is a hyperplane section of $Y$. Let $H_Y$ be the polarization of $Y$, and let $H_S$ be the polarization of $S$ (I guess $H_S = S \cap H_Y$), so $H_S^2$ is a degree $2$ class in the Chow ring of $S$.

> **Q1**: Am I correct in thinking that $i_*(H_S^2) = H_Y^3$?

In $S$, $H_S^2 = dP_S$ where $P_S$ is the class of a point in $S$ (but really, I think $H_S$ here can be replaced by any hyperplane of $S$, since we're working modulo rational equivalence), and $i$ is just an inclusion, so a point in $S$ should be taken to that same point, now considered as a point in $Y$. Since a point $P_Y$ in $Y$ satisfies $H_Y^3=dP_Y$, I think we should have $i_*(H_S^2) = H_Y^3$ - is this correct?

Secondly, a Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch calculation involving $i : S \hookrightarrow Y$ and a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $S$ would involve computing $i_*(\mathrm{ch}(\mathcal{F}) . \mathrm{td}(S))$ as the right-hand side of the GRR formula.

> **Q2**: Would it be correct to be using $H_S$ when explicitly writing out $\mathrm{ch}(\mathcal{F})$ and $\mathrm{td}(S)$ (and $H_Y$ when working out the left-hand side) in my situation of $i : S \hookrightarrow Y$ a hyperplane section?

Thanks.

Comment: GRR is a bit too much, use the projection formula.

Comment: To set it up maybe a bit better than I did in the question, we have $S=Y \cap H'$ a hyperplane section and $i : S \hookrightarrow Y$, where $H' \subset \mathbb{P}^N$ is some hyperplane, $H_Y=H \cap Y$ is the polarisation of $Y$, $H_S = i^* H_Y$ is the polarisation of $S$. Then using the projection formula we have $i_*(H_S^2)=i_*(i^*H_Y.i^*H_Y)=i_*(i^*H_Y).H_Y$ but I'm unsure how to proceed from here. I thought perhaps $i_*(i^*H_Y)=i_*(S.i^*H_Y)=i_*(S).H_Y=S.H_Y=H_Y^2$ because $S \sim H_Y$, but I'm not sure if the end of my argument is correct?

Comment: $i_*(H_S^2) = i_*((i^*H_Y)^2) = i_*(i^*(H_Y^2)) = i_*([S]\cdot i^*(H_Y^2)) = i_*([S]) \cdot H_Y^2 = H_Y \cdot H_Y^2 = H_Y^3$.

Comment: @Sasha Thank you